# Finding Jordan form base for $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 2 &1 &2 \\ -1 &0 &2 \\ 0&0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I need your help for understanding how to compute jordan base for this matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix}
2 &1  &2 \\ 
-1 &0  &2 \\ 
 0&0  & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

---

This is what I tried to do:

I found the Minimal polynomial: $(x-1)^{3}$,

so I know that the Jordan normal form is: $\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0  &0 \\ 
 1& 1 & 0\\ 
 0&1  & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

Now I remember that I need to find: $\ker (A-I), \ker (A-I)^{2}, \ker(A-I)^{3}$.

I found that $\ker (A-I)$ is: $\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
1 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\ker (A-I)^{2}$ is: $\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$

and obivously $\ker(A-I)^{3}$ is all  $\mathbb{R}^{3}$,
What should I do from here? I can't remember the whole algorithem, and I can't find it anywhere.

Thank you,
Have a great week-end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose a vector from $\ker(A-I)^{3}$ which is not in $\ker(A-I)^{2}$.

$\vec a=(0,0,1)^T$

$\vec b=(A-I)\vec a=A\vec a-\vec a=(2,2,0)^T$ belongs to $\ker(A-I)^{2}$ but not to $\ker(A-I)$.

$\vec c=(A-I)\vec b=(4,-4,0)$

The vectors $\vec c$, $\vec b$, $\vec a$ form a base in which the linear transformation $A$ has form $J$.

---

Two side notes:

- The <s>minimal polynomial</s> characteristic polynomial being $(x-1)^3$ does not determine the Jordan form uniquely. Only after you find out that the eigenspace has dimension 1 you know, that there is only one Jordan block. (EDIT: I meant the characteristic polynomial here - as pointed out in comments.)
- I have more often seen different form with 1's above the diagonal.

Comment: @Martin: Thank you for the answer.
If I found that the minimal polynomial is $(x-1)^3$, I know for sure that I must have a jordan block of size 3, so it leaves me with no other choices, right?

Comment: @Nir: you are right. @Martin: you might have mixed up the minimal polynomial with the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Why should I even need to compute $\ker (A-I)$? We don't use it anyway.

Comment: @Nir: you don't need to compute it. But knowing that it has dimension 1 is equivalent to showing that $(x-1)^3$ is the minimal polynomial (how did you show that?).

Comment: I simply showed that $(x-1)^{2}$ or $(x-1)$ is not 0.

Comment: @Fabian: Of course, you' re right, I was thinking about characteristic polynomial.